# Using softassert in Junit in place of TestNG…?

Tags: java, selenium, assert

I use soft assert in TestNG
here is my code

```
            if(!user.getUserreqmsg().isEmpty() ) {

               softAssert.assertEquals(createUser.getUsername_rqM(), user.getUserreqmsg());
            }
            if(!user.getUserlengthmsg().isEmpty()) {
                softAssert.assertEquals(createUser.getUsername_Min(), user.getUserlengthmsg());
            }
```

I want to change it to Junit or some spring test tool

Comment: ["*TestNG provides `org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert` class for soft asserts as it is more oriented towards functional testing. JUnit is a unit testing framework, so it does not provide any soft assertions.*"](https://automationrhapsody.com/soft-assertions-not-fail-junit-test/)

Comment: does soft asserts exist on other framwork , except TestNg

Comment: why you don't want to use testng ?

Answer (score 0):

Soft assert in junit can be achieved as :

**you can use:**

```
import org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions;
```

**Code:**

```
SoftAssertions softAssertions = new SoftAssertions();
softAssertions.assertThat(searchCriteriaPage.count()).isEqualTo(searchCriteria.getCount());
softAssertions.assertAll();
```

**Maven Dependency**

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1</version>

    </dependency>
```